# Combinatorial Proof of Derangement Identity $n!=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{n-i}D_i$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs, derangements

Let $D_n$ be the number of derangements of n objects. Find a combinatorial proof of the following identity:

$n! = D_n + \dbinom{n}{1} \cdot D_{n-1}+ \dbinom{n}{2} \cdot D_{n-2} + \cdots + \dbinom{n}{n-1} \cdot D_1 + \dbinom{n}{n} \cdot D_{0}$

This question has been somewhat asked and answered before here
[Finding a combinatorial proof of this identity: $n!=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{n-i}D_i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543117/finding-a-combinatorial-proof-of-this-identity-n-sum-i-0n-binomnn-id)

However, I need to come up with a combinatorial proof. I don't think the answer provided in the linked page is a combinatorial proof. When I learned about combinatorial proofs I was told they need to be more 'real life.' For example, in a committee of $n$ people, a subcommittee and a president must be chosen...

How can I write a true combinatorial proof for this identity?

Comment: The argument to which you linked *is* a combinatorial argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a combinatorial proof of this identity: $n!=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{n-i}D_i$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543117/finding-a-combinatorial-proof-of-this-identity-n-sum-i-0n-binomnn-id)

Comment: Brian- what exactly constitutes a combinatorial proof? I was always told that a combinatorial proof needs to tie into a real situation... like choosing a committee or determining the finishings in a race.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All permutations of $N$ objects have between $0$ and $N$ objects in their original position.  Then count each case, and add them all up:

- Pick zero objects to keep in their original position.  Scramble the remaining $N$ objects.
- Pick one object to keep in its original position.  Scramble the remaining $N-1$ objects.
- Pick two objects to keep in their original positions.  Scramble the remaining $N-2$ objects.
- ($N-4$ similar statements ...)
- Pick $N-1$ objects to keep in their original position.  Scramble the remaining $1$ object.
- Pick $N$ objects to keep in their original positions.  Scramble the remaining $0$ objects.

All of these cases have the same form:  "Pick $n$ objects out of $N$" has $_NC_n$ choices.  "Scramble $m$ objects" has $D_m$ choices.